# Apache rotatelogs not working

Tags: apache, svn, collabnet

Trying to use Apache's rotatelogs utility for rotating my Subversion access and error logs and below is my configuration:

```
ErrorLog "|/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/rotatelogs /var/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/logs/svn_errorlog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M"

CustomLog "|/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/rotatelogs /var/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/logs/svn_accesslog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M" common
```

and have commented out the default ErrorLog and CustomLog entries and did a restart.

but I don't see log rotation happening on the target directory.

I grepped the process id and rotatelogs process is alive

```
ps -ef|grep rotatelogs
root     25385 25384  0 08:16 ?        00:00:00 /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/rotatelogs /var/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/logs/svn_errorlog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M
root     25386 25384  0 08:16 ?        00:00:00 /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/rotatelogs /var/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/logs/svn_accesslog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M
root     25858 25384  0 08:16 ?        00:00:00 /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/rotatelogs /var/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/logs/svn_accesslog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M
2585     25827 24938  0 09:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep rotatelogs
```

I'm not sure where and how to debug and I'm looking to use the rotatelogs option not the logrotate utility.

OS - RHEL 6.8

svn server - svn, version 1.9.4 (r1740329)

[CollabNet flavor, not the CollabnetEdge]

> (P.S: Installed using the follwing
>   rpm:CollabNetSubversion-server-1.9.4- 2.x86_64.rpm )

Answer (score 1):

Did the log file size reach 5 MB? It won't rotate until then with the `5M` setting you have.

Comment: Thanks for your time, yes log file crossed beyond the file size.

 ls -lh

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 121M Feb 22 09:52 access_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29M Feb 22 09:43 error_log`

and a strange thing, whenever I restart the apache/SVN server, error log gets rotated like below.

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  537 Feb 22 08:16 svn_errorlog.2017-02-22-14_16_13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  537 Feb 22 09:42 svn_errorlog.2017-02-22-15_42_27
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  537 Feb 22 09:43 svn_errorlog.2017-02-22-15_42_59`